# Escaping html in java accented characters with number representation

Tags: java, html, escaping

I would like to escape some html text.

I'm using

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4("Identificación");
```

The output is:

```
Identificaci&oacute;n
```

This is correct. However I need a different ouput. I need the ouput with numeric representation of the characters. Something like:

```
Identificaci&#243;n
```

Do you know a library in java that can generate the output just like I need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open source **[Unbescape](http://www.unbescape.org)** library can do what you need. It will allow you to specify both an *escaping type* and a *level*. The former specifies the type of escaping you want (in your case it seems to be `HEXADECIMAL_REFERENCES`) and the latter what characters you want to escape (default is `LEVEL_2_ALL_NON_ASCII_PLUS_MARKUP_SIGNIFICANT`), which seems a right option for your use.

For example:

```
final String escaped =
    HtmlEscape.escapeHtml(text,
        HtmlEscapeType.HEXADECIMAL,
        HtmlEscapeLevel.LEVEL_2_ALL_NON_ASCII_PLUS_MARKUP_SIGNIFICANT);
```

Have a look at the usage here: http://www.unbescape.org/usingunbescape.html

Disclaimer, per StackOverflow rules: I'm Unbescape's author.

Comment: And if I want escape only accented characters, not markup signifiant ones?